# how to reference arguments with parameters in a function?

Tags: function, kotlin, class, methods, reference

```
class Score(
    val score:Int
){
    fun PersonalScore(){
        println(score)
    }

}
fun comPare(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int{
    var max = a
    if(max < b) max = b
    if(max < c) max = c
    println("The best score is $max")
    return max
}
fun main() {
    val score1 = Score(10)
    val score2 = Score(4)
    val score3 = Score(7)
    comPare(score1, score2, score3)  //this line is error
```

P/s: I'm a beginner and I don't know how to fix it. Please give me some guide, I'll be very grateful for your help. Thank you guys so much!!

can understand more deeply and practice more and more

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? (Most error messages are quite informative and will tell you what the problem is. And including the error message may help other people find this question if they hit the same problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the `comPare` function to take `Int` parameters. Your Score class is not an `Int`. It is a `Score`. It has a property inside it that is an `Int`. You must be very precise. If the parameter is defined as `Int`, you have to pass it an `Int`, not a `Score`.

So there are two different (mutually exclusive) solutions.

1. Pull the `Int` parameters out of your Score instances when passing them to the `comPare` function.
2. Change the `comPare` function to take `Score` parameters instead of `Int` parameters, and read the values out of the Score instance inside this function.

1:

```
fun main() {
    val score1 = Score(10)
    val score2 = Score(4)
    val score3 = Score(7)
    comPare(score1.score, score2.score, score3.score)
}
```

2:

```
fun comPare(a: Score, b: Score, c: Score): Int{
    var max = a.score
    if(max < b.score) max = b.score
    if(max < c.score) max = c.score
    println("The best score is $max")
    return max.score
}
```

Comment: Side notes: by convention, function names should start with a lower case letter. This helps distinguish them from constructors. So your `PersonalScore` function should be named `personalScore` instead. But actually, a function should always be named starting with a verb so it describes what it does, so it should really be named something like `printScore`. And "compare" is one word, so your `comPare` function should be named `compare`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
data class Score(val value: Int) {
    fun personalScore() {
        println(value)
    }
}

fun compareScores(score1: Score, score2: Score, score3: Score): Score {
    var maxScore = score1

    if (score2.value > maxScore.value) {
        maxScore = score2
    }

    if (score3.value > maxScore.value) {
        maxScore = score3
    }

    println("The best score is ${maxScore.value}")
    return maxScore
}

val score1 = Score(10)
val score2 = Score(4)
val score3 = Score(7)

val bestScore = compareScores(score1, score2, score3)
bestScore.personalScore()
```

The result is `The best score is 10`

Answer (score -1):

You should create getter and setters in you Score class.

```
class Score(){
val classLevelScore:Int = 0
    fun PersonalScore(){
        println(classLevelScore)
    }

   fun setScore(score:Int){
      classLevelScore = score
     }

   fun getScore():Int{
        return classLevelScore
     }

}
fun comPare(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int{
    var max = a
    if(max < b) max = b
    if(max < c) max = c
    println("The best score is $max")
    return max
}
fun main() {
    val score1 = Score()
    score1.setScore(10)
    val score2 = Score(4)
    score2.setScore(4)
    val score3 = Score(7)
    score3.setScore(7)
    comPare(score1.getScore(), score2.getScore(), score3.getScore())
}
```

so here we have score which is in class level. We are setting score through a method and getting that score through a method

Comment: This is a major antipattern in Kotlin because Kotlin uses properties, not getter/setter functions. The score is already accessible from your `classLevelScore` property.